# kubeadm init failing while initializing a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

execution logs from kubeadm init

- VM OS Version - RHEL 8.2 (4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64)
- Docker Version - 19.03.8
- Kubernetes Version - 1.18.0
- H/W Configuration - 4 CPU and 16 GB RAM (90% available)

```
$$kubeadm init --kubernetes-version="v1.18.0" --pod-network-cidr="10.244.0.0/16"

W0519 21:08:48.180818  913499 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.18.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
        [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
        [WARNING FileExisting-socat]: socat not found in system path
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [host422 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.180.40.75]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [host422 localhost] and IPs [10.180.40.75 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [host422 localhost] and IPs [10.180.40.75 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
W0519 21:08:50.681218  913499 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
W0519 21:08:50.681948  913499 manifests.go:225] the default kube-apiserver authorization-mode is "Node,RBAC"; using "Node,RBAC"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
        Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
                timed out waiting for the condition

        This error is likely caused by:
                - The kubelet is not running
                - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

        If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
                - 'systemctl status kubelet'
                - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

        Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
        To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.

        Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
                - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
                Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
                - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'

error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
```

kubelet status (could see `Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach` getting continuously printed in the logs)

```
 kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-05-19 21:08:48 IST; 17min ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 913672 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 18 (limit: 101228)
   Memory: 33.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─913672 /home0/kubernetes/kubernetes/server/bin/kubelet --root-dir=/home0/kubernetes/workdir

May 19 21:24:49 InBlrbnc422 kubelet[913672]: I0519 21:24:49.379623  913672 kubelet_node_status.go:294] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
May 19 21:24:59 InBlrbnc422 kubelet[913672]: I0519 21:24:59.425035  913672 kubelet_node_status.go:294] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
```

(1) Executed `swapoff -a`
(2) Tried updating the cgroup driver of docker and kubelet to systemd but somehow kubelet is not picking up the changes.Hope kubeadm init should be able to run with driver version cgroupfs.
Kindly let me know what else I need to check.

**UPDATE Stack**

```
couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init.runWaitControlPlanePhase
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/init/waitcontrolplane.go:114
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:234
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:422
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.NewCmdInit.func1
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:147
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:826
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:914
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:864
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
error execution phase wait-control-plane
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run.func1
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:235
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).visitAll
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:422
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow.(*Runner).Run
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/phases/workflow/runner.go:207
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd.NewCmdInit.func1
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/cmd/init.go:147
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:826
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:914
k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:864
k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app.Run
        /workspace/anago-v1.18.0-rc.1.21+8be33caaf953ac/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/app/kubeadm.go:50
main.main
        _output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kubeadm/kubeadm.go:25
runtime.main
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:203
runtime.goexit
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357
```

Answer (score 9):

Normally this issue due to the misconfiguration of your VM or packages. Try to perform these steps and it should work for you (all commands needs to be run as root):

First, reset your kubeadm cluster by running the reset command and flush your iptables (to avoid any networking issue)  :

```
kubeadm reset -f
iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X
```

Second, you need to change your Docker cgroup driver to systemd (recommended CRI conf for kubernetes kubelet by default) then restart docker service:

```
cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Finally you need to turn swapoff and  restart and enable kubelet services

```
swapoff -a
systemctl start kubelet
```

I did  install kubernetes using the exact same packages but I am using Kubernetes v1.21.0 and it works fine for me maybe you should upgrade that version if doesn't for you.

Comment: The ```kubeadm reset , swap -a and iptables were already flushed``` and tried w/o any success. Also as explained in my original post regarding the cgroupdriver change, the docker changes are getting reflected but somehow the kubelet(KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd under 10-kubeadm.conf) is not picking up systemd as the driver and always shows cgroupfs as the default driver.

Comment: cgroupDriver needs to be changed in the kubelet config file here /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml   Link : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/configure-cgroup-driver/ .

However I think it's not a blocker issue !! verify that the kubelet status is auto-restarting and enabled

Comment: Now the WARNING on cgroupDriver is resolved ( did pass the same in the kubelet.service under ExecStart). Remaining WARNING is ```[WARNING FileExisting-socat]: socat not found in system path```. Updated the original post with the traces received during kubeadm init. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Actually "socat" is a kubeadm dependency for sockets networking  so it must be installed with kubeadm , verify if it exist in your installed package list (sudo yum list installed | grep socat) if it doesn't exist it's so weird and in this case I recommend an upgrade for kubeadm to the v1.21.0 ( you could install it separately : sudo yum install  socat-1.7.3.3-2.el8 if you really need this version of kubeadm)  then restart everything (reset kubeadm stop kubelet run dockersystem prune delete all k8s conf and cni conf flush iptables and close your eyes  and hit the boom command "kubeadm init"  ;)

Comment: Here is a guide to compare with (the same release version as yours ): https://www.redaix.com/2020/06/how-to-install-and-configure-kubernetes.html